# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't use my dedicated AMD graphics card

Tags: drivers, 16.04, graphics, amd-graphics

I have an AMD R5 M330 graphics card, but my system won't use it. I've tried checking if there are any proprietary drivers available, but nothing showed up. I want to know if there's a way i could configure my system to use that graphics card instead of my integrated Intel graphics card.

```
lspci -v | grep ATI
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

Comment: Yet another one of *these* questions... <sigh> The long and the short of it is: **AMD drivers on 16.04 are a mess. Good luck.**

Answer (score 0):

Fglrx does not supported by Ubuntu 16.04 and amdgpu driver still does not support this gpu. So if you have integrated intel gpu, you have to stick to it.